# No segments* file found in RAMDirectory

Tags: java, lucene

I'm using Lucene to create an concept-based image search engine. Firstly, I open my database and copy it into a RAM index. Then I write an analyzer to find user input word and its synonym. At last, I want to open the index to get results.

[getImage()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRX19.png) - Used to call addDoc() copy database into my index

This is [getImageResult()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KB6uI.png) which I want to used to get result. I think maybe this is the bug.

However, if I remove:

```
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);

IndexWriter iwriter = new IndexWriter(index, config);
iwriter.commit();
```

It will raise an exception: no segments* file found in RAMDirectory.
And if I Keep this part, I can't get any result.

Comment: Please don't provide your code in screenshots. Copy it into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, but I assume you are trying to write to an index with your first snippet there, and then search it with the second, right?

Your `getImageResult()` method in opening a brand new index in a brand new directory. Anything previously written to a different `RAMDirectory` will not be available for you to search there.

You should either:

- Use the *same* `RAMDirectory` in both places, or
- Open your index in an `FSDirectory`, with which it will be saved to the file system, and can be reopened. See [`FSDirectory.open`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/store/FSDirectory.html#open-java.nio.file.Path-)